# JavaFx chart filter data

Tags: java, javafx

hi I am trying to use checkboxes to filter the data from a JSON into my javafx chart the problem I am having is that the data being pasted is being grouped by the row and not the column. so the filters filter each row meaning I have 100s of checkboxes whereas I only want to have one for each by the data variable.

below I have used Boolean flags to solve the problem, which in loading works however once I unselect a checkbox all the data disappears.

```
 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
   import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.List;
          import java.util.ResourceBundle;
  import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
  import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
  import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
  import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
     import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
   import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeDate.getYear;

  public class HyBridController implements Initializable {

private static String markup;
private static List<Recruits> recruits;

private static List<String> vehicle;
private static List<String> region;
private static List<String> year;
private static List<String> qtr;
private DashService service;

private CheckBox[] vehiclecheckBoxes;
private CheckBox[] regioncheckBoxes;
private CheckBox[] yearcheckBoxes;
  private CheckBox[] qtrcheckBoxes;
@FXML
private AnchorPane AnchorPane1;

@FXML
private HBox HBox1;
@FXML
private HBox hbox2;
@FXML
private NumberAxis yAxis;

@FXML
private CategoryAxis xAxis;

@FXML
private BarChart<?, ?> BarChart1;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    service = new DashService();
    service.setAddress("http://glynserver.cms.livjm.ac.uk/DashService/SalesGetSales");
    service.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent e) -> {
        markup = e.getSource().getValue().toString();

        recruits = (new Gson()).fromJson(markup, new TypeToken<LinkedList<Recruits>>() {
        }.getType());

        region= recruits.stream().map(o -> o.getRegion()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        vehicle = recruits.stream().map(o -> o.getVehicle()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        qtr = recruits.stream().map(o -> o.getRe()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        year = recruits.stream().map(o -> o.getYear()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());


        constructCheckBoxes(); 
    });

    service.start();
}

private void constructCheckBoxes() {
    vehiclecheckBoxes = new CheckBox[vehicle.size()];
    regioncheckBoxes = new CheckBox[region.size()];
    yearcheckBoxes = new CheckBox[year.size()];
    qtrcheckBoxes = new CheckBox[qtr.size()];


    for (byte index = 0; index < vehicle.size(); index++) {
        vehiclecheckBoxes[index] = new CheckBox(vehicle.get(index));

        vehiclecheckBoxes[index].setSelected(true);
        vehiclecheckBoxes[index].addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            constructSeries();
        });

        HBox1.getChildren().add(vehiclecheckBoxes[index]);
    }

    for (byte index = 0; index < region.size(); index++) {
        regioncheckBoxes[index] = new CheckBox(region.get(index));

        regioncheckBoxes[index].setSelected(true);
        regioncheckBoxes[index].addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            constructSeries();
        });

        HBox1.getChildren().add(regioncheckBoxes[index]);
    }
     for (byte index = 0; index < year.size(); index++) {
        yearcheckBoxes[index] = new CheckBox(year.get(index));

        yearcheckBoxes[index].setSelected(true);
        yearcheckBoxes[index].addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            constructSeries();
        });

        HBox1.getChildren().add(yearcheckBoxes[index]);
    }
      for (byte index = 0; index < qtr.size(); index++) {
        qtrcheckBoxes[index] = new CheckBox(qtr.get(index));

        qtrcheckBoxes[index].setSelected(true);
        qtrcheckBoxes[index].addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            constructSeries();
        });

        HBox1.getChildren().add(qtrcheckBoxes[index]);
    }
    AnchorPane1.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
    constructSeries();
}

private void constructSeries() {
    BarChart1.getData().clear();

   for (Recruits recruit : recruits){
        boolean flag = false;
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        for (CheckBox cb : regioncheckBoxes){
            if (!cb.isSelected()){
                series.setName(cb.getText());
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        for (CheckBox cb : vehiclecheckBoxes){
            if (!cb.isSelected()){
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        for (CheckBox cb : yearcheckBoxes){
            if (!cb.isSelected()){
                flag = true;
            }
        }

          for (CheckBox cb : qtrcheckBoxes){
            if (!cb.isSelected()){
                flag = true;
            }
        }


        if (!flag){
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(recruit.getVehicle(), recruit.getQuantity()));
            BarChart1.getData().add(series);
        }

    }
}

private static class DashService extends Service<String> {

    private StringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address.set(address);
    }

    public final String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
    }

    public final StringProperty addressProperty() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {
            private URL url;
            private HttpURLConnection connect;
            private String markup = "";

            @Override
            protected String call() {
                try {
                    url = new URL(getAddress());
                    connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    connect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    markup = (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()))).readLine();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (connect != null) {
                        connect.disconnect();
                    }
                }

                return markup;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Probably the scope of the boolean is not good and it applies to each row instead of each individual data item. Not sure what you are asking here, is the data for each row disappearing or for the whole app?

Comment: the data for the whole app disappears when I unselect any checkbox

Comment: It's hard to tell with the code you are showing, but looking at all those for loops, have you tried adding a break statement after `flag = true`? Because that code looks like it could indeed empty all the data at once if something isn't right. When `flag = true` what happens then? By default, are the checkboxes selected or not selected?

Comment: all selected I have put all my code up now.

Comment: any idea WonderWorld?

Comment: No not yet. Have you debugged your code and set breakpoints at the block of for loops with the if statement `(!cb.isSelected())` and what `flag = true` does to see if the problem lies there?

Comment: yes i have tried this but still no luck